# Edit on mobile app shows old text

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app

I found a [question on Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142333/250) that I had previously edited (the user had written it both in English and Spanish and I removed the English part).

Today I found that the user added a comment with the code:

[image: screenshot before edit]

I decided to add that comment into the question itself, tapped on the edit link, and found that the text displayed in the box is not the current one, but the original text in English and Spanish:

[image: screenshot after clicking edit]

After a quick check, it doesn’t happen on the mobile or desktop website. It seems it only affects the app. I am using an IPhone 6 with iOS 11.2.6.

I tried to replicate the issue in other questions, but I haven’t been able to do it. The issue only seems to happen on that one. I don’t remember trying to edit that question on mobile before, but maybe that could be the case (could it be caching a previous value?).

Comment: Sounds like the same issue I had here: [iOS app "edit" link populates with incorrect revision](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/288814) I don't think it's happened to me since though so no idea what's going on

Comment: @Cai probably the bug is with a draft which wasn't cleared once submitting, for some reason. Isn't there "clear draft" button somewhere?

Comment: I didn’t see any “clear draft” button. After adding the changes, the old next is gone; and if I click on edit, it’s all the new text. It seems it was caching. I will try to run a test (editing without saving) and see what happens, if not, I will close the ticket as it cannot be replicated anymore.

Comment: @Sha the incorrect revision came from an edit made from review (in both mine and this case) and you can't review from the app so the draft never existed in the app.